# Set/Change PID / VID on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: usb, raspi-config, pi-pico

I want to change the Product ID and Vendor ID of my Raspy Pico. After some research I found the TinyUSB library and there seems to be settings for Device Descriptor. As soon as I integrate the library in my program however, the USB doesn´t show up on my Device Manager anymore (device manager isn´t even refreshing when I plug the raspy in). I want the raspberry to show up under "USB controller" with a custom PID, VID and device descripton. I´m programing in C in Visual Studio Code on Windows. Is there an example on how to change the PID, VID and device descripton?

Was working with this function from "usb_descriptors.c":

```
#define USB_VID   0xCafe
#define USB_BCD   0x0200

tusb_desc_device_t const desc_device =
{
    .bLength            = sizeof(tusb_desc_device_t),
    .bDescriptorType    = TUSB_DESC_DEVICE,
    .bcdUSB             = USB_BCD,

    // Use Interface Association Descriptor (IAD) for CDC
    // As required by USB Specs IAD's subclass must be common class (2) and protocol must be IAD (1)
    .bDeviceClass       = TUSB_CLASS_MISC,
    .bDeviceSubClass    = MISC_SUBCLASS_COMMON,
    .bDeviceProtocol    = MISC_PROTOCOL_IAD,
    .bMaxPacketSize0    = CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE,

    .idVendor           = USB_VID,
    .idProduct          = USB_PID,
    .bcdDevice          = 0x0100,

    .iManufacturer      = 0x01,
    .iProduct           = 0x02,
    .iSerialNumber      = 0x03,

    .bNumConfigurations = 0x01
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would make sense to post your code, as I doubt anyone will be able to help otherwise.

Comment: done! I assume this function should bring the pico usb to default values

Comment: I am in the same boat. I have found I can update an sdk file to set these values but I believe there should be an override method

Comment: I think the problem is - by default, the Pico runs a TinyUSB stack in which it creates a UART device and pipes printfs (et al) to it. But when you start writing your own TinyUSB code (I think including bits vi CMake) it doesn't do this - so you can do it all yourself. BUT - you're not implementing and registering a complete device here - so all you've done it just inhibit the automatic initialization of the first stuff I mentioned.